# C# Windows Forms Web Api authentication

Tags: c#, winforms, api

I have a problem with accessing data from [this](http://api.football-data.org) web site.
Here is my code:

```
public static string CallRestMethod(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webrequest.Method = "GET";
            webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(),enc);
            string result = string.Empty;
            result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            webresponse.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

What should I add to authenticate to this token:

```
'X-Auth-Token: YOUR_API_TOKEN';
```

Comment: This simply seems to be a matter to add an header to the webrequest

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: _webrequest.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "YOUR_API_TOKEN");_

Comment: Thank you very much